# Red card during substitution in Football

Tags: rules, football

Can a player in football be given a red card during substitution because of entering the field long before the player being substituted exits? I'm curious to know this because in most of the matches that I've watched, the new player only enters after the substituted player exits

Comment: @Nij, this is not a duplicate as OP asks about a red card given to the *replacing* player (not the replaced one).

Comment: Yellow can be given, red? No.

Comment: A second yellow card and therefore red card can be given to a substitute or to a player about to be substituted. Likely it would not be, but you're making a blanket statement which is not correct. @Don_Biglia

Comment: The question has the same answer: any player can get their first or second card of either colour, regardless of whether they could be, have been, will be, are about to be, or are currently being substituted on or off. @Bebs

Comment: @Nij,please don't beat about the bushes

Comment: @Nij, in fact a yellow/red card can be given for many reasons so most answers of these kind of questions would be "Yes, it could happen". Answering "No, it never happened." to this question would very hard to prove. My guess is that OP was also asking for a reference of this situation, he probably could find references of red card given to the player going out, but not to the entering player.

Comment: The question is quite clearly "can it be done?" not "has it ever been done?". The answer is trivially that yes, the referee is empowered to give cards correct in law to any player or substitute or substituted player between the time they enter the ground until the time they leave it after the match, but as a practical matter, it is extremely unlikely that this exact precise combination of events has occurred in a context where it will be accessible to the community here. @Bebs

Comment: ... Therefore, the question as written is a duplicate as voted; any supposed additional question about actual events should be be separate from both.

Comment: @Nij A second yellow card leading to a red card is still a yellow card. There is a distinction (for me at least).The act of entering the pitch too early would never be seen as such a violence to give an immediate red card for it. I read the question as such.

Comment: @Don_Biglia, the substitute could have received a yellow earlier on the bench. Then the second yellow for entering too soon.

Comment: A dismissal for a second caution is still a dismissal and carries identical weight in the laws. Red cards are red cards, regardless of why they were given. @Don_Biglia

Comment: @Bebs I was not disputing that it wasn't possible. Just saying that this infriction alone would not trigger a direct red card on its own because the punishment for it would only be a yellow. Nij, I knew something like that would come, kinda why I added the for me bit. If a referee gives a second yellow resulting in red I view it differently. And so did the referee, if he deemed it grave enough he would give straight red regardless of him being booked already. And in game yes, but for further actions/suspensions a direct red card could not carry the same weight in the laws. But thats anthr dis

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The suggested duplicate is about *player*s who are leaving being cautioned/sent-off, not *substitute*s who are entering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no, but they may be cautioned (which may indirectly result in a send-off for a second caution).

However, this question demonstrates why it is important to get the terminology used in the Laws of the Game correct so that there is no ambiguity.

As defined throughout [Law 3 - The Players](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players/chapters/number-of-players):

- A *player* is one of the (up to) 11 active participants in the match.
- A *substitute* is one of the potential replacements for a player, who must be named before the match.
- A *substituted player* is a participant who was previously a player and was replaced by a substitute and may not take any further part in the match.

As defined in [3.3 - Substitution Procedure](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players/chapters/substitution-procedure), when a substitution occurs - a *player* becomes a *substituted player* and a *substitute* becomes a *player*. If return substitutions are in use for the match, the *player* instead becomes a *substitute* (that is, they may be used again).

Now to answer the question, which appears to be about a *substitute* entering the field too early (not a *player*), the [substitution procedure](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players/chapters/substitution-procedure) also states:

> The substitute only enters:
>
> - during a stoppage in play
> - at the halfway line
> - after the player being replaced has left
> - after receiving a signal from the referee

The [infringements and sanctions](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players/chapters/infringements-and-sanctions) section of Law 3 - The Players (section 3.5) states:

> For any other infringements of this Law:
>
> - the players<sup>1</sup> are cautioned
> - play is restarted with an indirect free kick, from the position of the ball when play was stopped<sup>2</sup>

<sub>1 - I've just gone on a tirade about using the correct terminology, and here we have an example of the Laws themselves being incorrect. This sanction does not just apply to *players*, but also to *substitutes* and *substituted players*.</sub>

<sub>2 - This is only if the offence happened while the ball was still in play and isn't one punished by a direct free kick. If the ball was still in play, and as in this specific example, the substitute has entered the field incorrectly, the restart is a direct free kick [[3.7](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players/chapters/extra-persons-on-the-field-of-play)]. If the ball is out of play, play restarts with the previous restart [[12.4](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/restart-of-play-after-fouls-and-misconduct)].</sub>

Therefore in practice, if substitutes are entering the field before the other player has left during the substitution procedure, in practice:

- If the offence is only minor, the referee will use their discretion granted by [Law 5, Section 2, Paragraph 1](http://theifab.com/laws/the-referee/chapters/decisions-of-the-referee) to either ignore the offence or warn the team to adhere to the correct substitution procedure.
- If the offence is blatant or the procedure continues being flouted by a team after having been warned, the referee will ask the substitute to leave the field, caution them for [entering or re-entering the field of play without the referee’s permission](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/restart-of-play-after-fouls-and-misconduct), and have them then re-enter the field correctly (provided by that point the player being substituted has left) to complete the substitution procedure correctly and become a valid player.
- If this is the substitute's second caution, they are [sent off for receiving a second caution in the same match](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/disciplinary-action) and instead do not re-enter the field as a player after being sanctioned. Since they never became a player (and the player leaving never became a substitute / substituted player), the team does not play short. They may either opt for the player that was being replaced to continue, or use another substitute (if there are any eligible substitutes remaining).